# Rails scope for sorting most recent children, and including those without children

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have the first part of this working. I can successfully call the most recent `List` with this :

```
scope :most_recent_chats, -> { 
  where(list_type: 'my').joins(:chat_lines)
  .where('chat_lines.created_at = (SELECT MAX(chat_lines.created_at) FROM chat_lines where chat_lines.list_id = lists.id)')
  .group('lists.id')
}
```

However, if a `List` has no `chat_lines`, it doesn't get returned.

My question is, how can I return all `List`'s sorted by their most recent children ( `chat_lines` ), even if they don't have children.

Comment: What field would you be looking for if the list has no chat_lines?

Comment: @MichaelGorman I would be looking for `lists.created_at` if a `list` has no children.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The RAILS joins method performs an *Inner* joins (records with matches in both tables). What you are looking for is a *Left Outer* joins call (records in the first table that may have records in the second).  In rails 5 `left_outer_joins` does this type of call, in rails 4 and below  you have to be explicit by doing `join('LEFT OUTER JOIN "chat_lines" ON "chat_lines"."list_id" = "list"."id"')`

For more information on the different type of joins call go to https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

For more information on the Rails joins methods
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#joining-tables

For Rails 4

```
where(list_type: 'my').join('LEFT OUTER JOIN "chat_lines" ON "chat_lines"."list_id" = "list"."id"')
  .order("GREATEST(chat_lines.created_at, list.created_at) DESC").limit(1).first
```

For Rails 5

```
where(list_type: 'my').left_outer_joins(:chat_lines)
  .order("GREATEST(chat_lines.created_at, list.created_at) DESC").limit(1).first
```

Comment: This seems like the correct answer, but I'm getting an `undefined method`. I'm on Rails 4.0 . Is this Rails 5?

Comment: It looks like it is a rails 5 thing, for rails 4 you will just have to be explicit in your joins call, `join('LEFT OUTER JOIN "chat_lines" ON "chat_lines"."list_id" = "list"."id"')`

Comment: Ah that's a great idea. That though, coupled with my `.where` query seems to still only return records with children. I probably should rethink my `select` statement. I feel like that's the line being exclusory

Comment: You probably could use the MYSQL GREATER() method to compare the list created at with chat_line created at, and sort by the result